# Detect target write fields so that they can be backed up and potentially restored

Tags: php, mysql, rollback

Basically, I am trying to create an interface that will tell an administrator "Hey, we ran this query, and we weren't so sure about it, so if it broke things click here to undo it".

The easiest way I can think to do this is to somehow figure out what tables and cells an identified "risky" query writes to, and store this data along with some bookkeeping data in a "backups" table, so that if necessary the fields can be repopulated with their original contents.

How do I go about figuring out which fields get overwritten by a particular (possibly complicated) mysql command?

**Edit:** "risky" in terms of completing successfully but doing unwanted things, not in terms of throwing an error or failing and leaving the system in an inconsistent state.

Comment: use transaction, disable auto commit, `begin .... end`, no error, then commit

Comment: unless i misunderstand, trasactions may not be of much help. This administrator will look at commands that ran and were successful days or weeks ago, and choose to roll them back if necessary

Comment: days or week ago? i afraid there is no good solution, as the data will growth after the patch, if you backup a copy before the patching, but that snapshot will not catch up with any latest changes. so, my point is there is no simple undone

Comment: The assumption here is that most data in there is independent. Basically, what I need to do is given a SQL query, determine exactly where it writes so I can snag that data before it gets overwritten. Note: i'm not trying to roll the entire system back -- just that one request, and assume no side effects

Comment: i think is just simple a sql like `insert into new_table select id, column from the_table;` will do? (this is to keep your original column value)

Comment: something like that will probably suffice for the actual backing up part, but the main point of the question is how to figure out what `id`, `column` and `the_table` are. Refer to the third paragraph: given a potentially long and complicated query, how can you figure out exactly what tables and columns it will write to?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following things:
- add an AFTER UPDATE trigger to every table you want to monitor
- create a copy of every table (example: [yourtable]_backup) you want to monitor
- in all AFTER UPDATE triggers, add code: INSERT INTO yourtable_backup VALUES(OLD.field1, OLD.field2..., OLD.fieldN)

How it works: the AFTER UPDATE trigger detects an update of the table, and backups the old values into the backup table

Important: you need to use INNODB table format for triggers to work. Triggers don't work with MyISAM tables.

You may add a timestamp field to the backup tables to know when each row was inserted.

Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html